# Python3 под Linux: ограничить использование процессора, а потом снять ограничения

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-3.5

В Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya (Kernel: 4.8.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit)) пишу скрипт на Python 3.5.2, откуда пытаюсь запускать при помощи `subprocess.call` программу, которая сильно нагружает процессор и иногда полностью виснет. Хочу задать ограничения ей при помощи модуля [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html), что удаётся:

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (10, 10))   # задаю ограничения
print(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU))      # вывод: (10, 10)

# subprocess.call(['./resource_consuming_program',])  # буду здесь вызывать 
                                                      # тяжёлую программу потом
```

Однако, когда я пытаюсь снять ограничения для дальнейшей работы других частей скрипта

```
resource.setrlimit(                                   # больше не хочу
    resource.RLIMIT_CPU,                              # чтоб ограничения
    (resource.RLIM_INFINITY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY)  # действовали
)
```

возникает ошибка:

```
ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit
```

Проблема в следующем: мне эти ограничения менять необходимо, потому что есть часть, которая работает долго (но уже надёжно), и для неё надо каким-то образом увеличивать или вовсе снимать ограничения на время процессора, что и представляет трудность для меня.

**P.S.** Я вижу, что модуль resource находится в разделе Unix Specific Services, но там в некоторых местах в качестве доступных ОС указаны определённые версии Linux, поэтому я полагаю, что использование этого модуля всё же возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для того, что бы повышать подобные ограничения - Вам нужны права рута. Что бы работать в пределах ограничений - не нужно.

Поэтому, перед изменениями запоминайте текущие ограничения и выставляйте их вместо INFINITY

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не трогать родительский процесс, можно после fork изменять ограничения на ресурсы:

```
import resource
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('program',
    preexec_fn=lambda: resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (10, 10)))
```

[Python: ulimit and nice for subprocess.call / subprocess.Popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1689505/4279)